# While Adding Git Repository Jenkins throwing error "Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git.exe ls-remote -h"

Tags: jenkins

I am adding Git repository to Jenkins in Source code management it throwing error Failed to connect to repository:

> Error performing git command: git.exe ls-remote -h

[image]

Answer (score 1):

localhost:8080/configureTools, path to git executable C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe